# Como puedo modificar atributos de un objeto, con sus propios metodos PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, poo, atributos, metodos

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python usando POO, resulta que quiero crear una clase que tenga un método que sea capaz de modificar atributos de la misma clase, colocare un código de ejemplo para que entiendan mi idea:

```
class cola:

    #ATRIBUTOS DE LA CLASE
    arregloElementos = []
    posInicial, posFinal = 0, 0
    numElementos = 0
    nomCola = ""


    #Inicializa al objeto
    def __init__(self, elementos, nombre):
        self.numElementos = elementos
        self.nomCola = nombre
        print("Se creo la cola: %s" %self.nomCola)


    #Indica que mostrar cuando se llame al objeto mismo
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.arregloElementos}"

    #Metodo para ingresar un elemento mas al arreglo
    def insertar(self, dato):
        self.arregloElementos.append(dato)

 # +++++ PROGRAMA +++++
 colaCaja1 = cola(10, "Caja 1")
 colaCaja2 = cola(5, "Caja 2")

 print(colaCaja1)
 print(colaCaja2)

 colaCaja1.insertar(10)
 colaCaja2.insertar(20)

 print(colaCaja1)
 print(colaCaja2)
```

Y la salida en el terminal es:

```
Se creo la cola: Caja 1
Se creo la cola: Caja 2
[]                       //Muestra la lista vacia correcta
[]                       //Muestra la lista vacia correcta
[10, 20]                 //Aqui deberia mostrarme oslamente [10]  
[10, 20]                 //Y aqui solamente [20]
```

Como ven, quiero crear un objeto y luego al momento de llamar al método "insertar" poder agregar un elemento nuevo al final de la lista, el problema que tengo es que cuando ejecuto el código no me sale ningun error, pero si me muestras dos arreglos IDENTICOS, o sea, parece que en vez de modificar el atributo arregloElementos de cada objeto por separado, modifica el atributo de la misma clase y tal vez por eso muestra eso, supongo eso porque si pongo al revés los métodos y primero pongo colaCaja2.insertar(20) y luego colaCaja2.insertar(10) sale una lista idéntica en ambos casos pero primero el 20 y luego el 10.
Entonces ¿Cómo podría hacer para utilizar un método dentro de la misma clase y que modifique sus atributos pero para cada objeto con el que la llamo y no de manera global, podrían indicarme qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: estas mostrando el contenido de la lista completo, es la misma y se guardan ambos datos ahi, lo que podrias hacer es imprimir por inidice segun la posicion, pero creo que no resuelve tu problema

Comment: Si querés que cada objeto tenga su propio atributo "arregloElementos", NO uses atributos de clase (que son compartidos por todas las instancias), usa de instancia (por ejemplo, dentro de \_\_init\_\_ hacer self.arregloElementos = [])

Comment: Excelente ayuda Dante S. tenias razón eso soluciono el problema completamente, Muchas Gracias!!!